# Best way to insert an already parsed XML into Excel Sheets in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to find a best way to avoid repetitive code to Insert the Parsed XML into the Excel sheets. I have 10 DIFFERENT parent XML nodes and their respective child nodes. For each Parent, the child nodes can vary between 1 and 8. For example, Parent1 will have 3 child nodes, parent2 will have 2 child nodes and so on.

Is there any way I can avoid this repetition. Please find my code below for 2 parents:

```
For Each xParent In xNode.ChildNodes
    For Each xChild In xParent.ChildNodes
        If (xParent.nodeName = "G_PARENT1") Then
            If (xChild.nodeName = "CHILD1") Then
                parent1Count = parent1Count + 1
                Worksheets("PARENT1SHEET").Cells(parent1Count, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
                Worksheets("PARENT1SHEET").Cells(parent1Count, 1).Value = xChild.text
            ElseIf (xChild.nodeName = "CHILD2") Then
                Worksheets("PARENT1SHEET").Cells(parent1Count, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                Worksheets("PARENT1SHEET").Cells(parent1Count, 2).Value = xChild.text
            ElseIf (xChild.nodeName = "CHILD3") Then
                Worksheets("PARENT1SHEET").Cells(parent1Count, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
                Worksheets("PARENT1SHEET").Cells(parent1Count, 3).Value = xChild.text
            End If
        End If

        If (xParent.nodeName = "G_PARENT2") Then
            If (xChild.nodeName = "CHILD4") Then
                parent2Count = parent2Count + 1
                Worksheets("PARENT2SHEET").Cells(parent2Count, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
                Worksheets("PARENT2SHEET").Cells(parent2Count, 1).Value = xChild.text
            ElseIf (xChild.nodeName = "CHILD5") Then
                Worksheets("PARENT2SHEET").Cells(parent2Count, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                Worksheets("PARENT2SHEET").Cells(parent2Count, 2).Value = xChild.text
            End If
        End If
    Next xChild
Next xParent
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions to validate the parent and child node names and retrieve the index values. The rest is plain sailing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test(ByVal root As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode)

    Const MAX_PARENTS As Integer = 10
    Dim ParentNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim ChildNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim reParent As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim reChild As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim match As VBScript_RegExp_55.match
    Dim targetRow(1 To MAX_PARENTS) As Long
    Dim targetSheet As String
    
    ' Regular expression to match the parent node name.
    reParent.Pattern = "^G_PARENT(\d+)$"
    
    ' Regular expression to match the child node name.
    reChild.Pattern = "^CHILD(\d+)$"

    For Each ParentNode In root.ChildNodes
        
        ' Validate the node name.
        Set match = reParent.Execute(ParentNode.nodeName)
        
        If match Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Node is not a parent node."
            Exit For
        End If
        
        ' Get the parent index.
        parentIndex = match.SubMatches(0)
        
        ' Make sure there is a least one child node.
        If ParentNode.ChildNodes.Length = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Parent node with no child nodes."
            Exit For
        End If
        
        For Each ChildNode In ParentNode.ChildNodes
                
            ' Validate the node name.
            Set match = reChild.Execute(ChildNode.nodeName)
            
            If match Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Node is not a child node."
                Exit For
            End If
            
            ' Get the child index.
            childIndex = match.SubMatches(0)
            
            targetSheet = "PARENT" & parentIndex & "SHEET"
            targetRow(parentIndex) = targetRow(parentIndex) + 1
            
            ' It's not clear to me from your example how to calculate the target colum,
            ' so I'll leave that up to you.
            
            With Worksheets(targetSheet).Cells(targetRow(parentIndex), targetColumn)
                .NumberFormat = "@"
                .Value = ChildNode.Text
            End With
            
        Next ChildNode
        
    Next ParentNode
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this.  I am extracting the numeric parts of the parent and child nodes.  If the numbers get more complex than they were in your example you might have to do something more complex than just taking the right most character, but for the example you gave it is sufficient. It's worth noting that if you just name the sheets the same thing as the nodes, you won't have to do any parsing at all, you can just `Set this = sheets(xParent.nodeName)`

I use .usedRange.rows.count + 1 to get the next empty row on whichever sheet you are writing to.  I use mod here on the child node name to map child4 and child5 to columns 1 and 2.

```
Dim this As Worksheet

For Each xParent In xNode.ChildNodes
    
    parentNum = Right(xParent.nodeName, 1)
    Set this = Worksheets("PARENT" & parentNum & "SHEET")
    r = this.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    For Each xChild In xParent.ChildNodes
    
        cNum = Right(xChild.nodeName, 1)
        c = cNum Mod 3
        If c = 0 Then c = 3
        
        this.Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "@"
        this.Cells(r, c) = xChild.Text
        
        Next
    Next
```